# Cant identify the issue in the mysql request

Tags: c#, mysql

I have two functions and one is working perfectly and the other is not, the code is the same apart from that the non functioning code has a WHERE in the database request, I just cant get it to work and I am desperate. The cID is a string given to the function and thats the ONLY thing that is correct at the moment

```
Geotag c = new Geotag();
String myConnection = WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["mydatabase"].ConnectionString;
MySqlConnection myConn = new MySqlConnection(myConnection);
String strSQL = "SELECT Id,geotag,item,date,nameofplace FROM geolist WHERE Id = 'cID';";
MySqlCommand myCommand = new MySqlCommand();
myCommand.Connection = myConn;
myCommand.CommandText = strSQL;
try
{
    myConn.Open();
    MySqlDataReader myReader;
    myReader = myCommand.ExecuteReader();
    myReader.Read();

    while (myReader.Read())
    {
```

my reader is empty so it skips and moves on....why? i tried what i belive is everything, like without ' ' around the cID string.

If I remove the WHERE = cID I will directly be given an object back that is the first in the list so I know the code works. The database has the matched string and even if I hard code the string into the WHERE it still wont work so its something else I am missing here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are comparing an Id field, so you'll have probably one record back but you are calling the `Read` method twice

```
myReader.Read();

while (myReader.Read()) // <--- empty
```

Comment: You are right, Thanks Tormek! I have no idea why i did not spot that the times i gone thrue the method in debug.